# Background image resize by itself

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm a little bit desesparate, i have tried multiple things and nothing is working. So my issue is the following :
Everytime i click on a input field, the background resize by himself, i have a blank space on the bottom and on the top.

I have added :
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
        // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
});
```

})

login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" align-title="left">
<ion-content class="background">
    <div class="hero no-header flat">
        <div class="content" style="bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="app-icon"></div>
            <h1 style="text-transform: uppercase;">App</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list padding" style="margin-top: 25px;">

        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px; display: block;">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Adresse e-mail" ng-model="data.email" class="customInput">
        </label>
        <label style="margin-bottom: 20px; display: block;">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" ng-model="data.password" class="customInput">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="button-bar padding">
        <button class="button button-small button-border icon-left ion-social-google button-assertive-900" ng-click="login(data)">Connexion</button>
        <button class="button button-small button-border icon-left ion-social-facebook button-positive-900">Facebook</button>
    </div>
    <div class="padding">
        <button class="button button-full button-register ink" ui-sref="app.register">Créer votre compte</button>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

```
    .background.scroll-content {
    background: url('../img/login.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

**The issue is that when the keyboard is shown the background resizes or the keyboard pushes the background image up.**

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, please explain better. I've tried your code here: http://play.ionic.io/app/e9abbb2a5670 but I dont se anything wrong.

Comment: That should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have added more information at the end of my post, it's related to the keyboard.